# Trying to embed the natural numbers in $[0,1]$

Tags: analysis, real-numbers

This seems to be very easy but I don't see it. How can I embed $\mathbb N$ in $[0,1]$ with a function? I have a function $\phi:\mathbb N\rightarrow\mathbb R$ with $\phi(n) = \beta^n$ for $0<\beta<1$. I want to write down a function $\varphi:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R$ that basically does the same as $\phi$ (i.e. has the same graph but continuous).

To be more formal: I have to find a function $\varphi$ mapping $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$ such that for every $n\in\mathbb N$ there exists a $x\in[0,1]$ such that $\varphi(x) = \phi(n)$.

Comment: For $0<n<1$ ???

Comment: It is not clear to me what you really want. If it is an injective function from $\mathbb N$ to $[0, 1]$ you may consider $\varphi: \mathbb N\rightarrow [0, 1]$ given by $$\varphi(n):=\frac{1}{2^n}.$$

Comment: There was a typo, ofc I meant $0<\beta<1$. 

@ptf: But $\varphi$ maps from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$, not $\mathbb N$.

If I plot the the graph of $\phi$, $\phi(n)$ decays geometrically as $n$ approaches $\infty$. Now I want basically the same for a function $\varphi$ mapping from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$. Or, in other words, I seek a function $\varphi$ from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$ such that for any $n\in\mathbb N$, there exists a $x\in[0,1]$ such that $\varphi(x) = \phi(n)$.

Comment: It's good that you try to be more formal, but it's still probably not what you want. Because you could just take $\varphi(x)=x$.

Answer (score 1):

Take the funcion $f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(n)=\frac{n+1}{n+2}$. This function preserves the order and its image is isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$.